# Excel =RIGHT formula not working

Tags: macos, microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

i have the problem that a `=RIGHT` function is not working in my Excel-Sheet.
I used the following function
`=RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-SEARCH(":",A2))`

It should output me the string after `:`.

Excel prompts

> There is a problem with your formula

I am using Excel for Mac v16.20 on MacOS 10.14.4.

Thank you

Comment: What do you have in A2 ? the formula works fine for me when testing

Comment: This probably isn't very useful for you, but it worked fine with that formula looking at the string `test:exportthis` on Windows 10/Office 365

Comment: For my test I used `ABC:DEF` in A2. I know that this formula should work right. So my main question is, how comes it prompts an error in _my_ excel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be your regional settings are different and require ; (semi-colon) instead of ,(comma)

Comment: That means function name or cell name is incorrect